# Email - what's the point of setting it up in the web.config

Tags: c#, .net, email

I'm trying to get email working in my application. In my web.config I have:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="myemail@email.com">
            <network host="A host address" port="37" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Now in the code I new up a SmtpClient();

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
```

Then I have to go ahead and set the port and host?

```
client.Host = "A host address";
client.Port = 37;
```

I'm confused by this. I don't understand the point of setting them in the webconfig if when you new up a SmtpClient you have to go ahead and set the variables.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you've set it up in the web.config the host and port should already be set on the SmtpClient object when you use the default constructor

Comment: that's what I was thinking but it's not

Comment: you were right. I think it wasn't working because I was checking from a unit test where for some reason it wasn't getting set. In the actual app it is. I'm guessing this is because to get it working in test you would probably need a config attribute for the executing assembly being the test project?

Comment: Right...  yes the web.config for your web application won't get picked up by your test project, you will need to add the same config in the test projects app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the `deliveryMethod` attribute.  Change your config to:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="myemail@email.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network host="A host address" port="37" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample of how you should be setting your system.net in web.config.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="info@somedomain.com">            
        <network 
            host="smtp.sendgrid.com"
            port="587" 
            userName="stackoverflow"
            password="qwertyuiuioopp"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```